# How to use IF or CASE for two SQL queries JOINED going through each record

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to use `IF` or `CASE` statements while going through each record for two JOINED SQL queries.

Each `AccountID(AccountSDIF)` has its own own unique account created date and Account's task created date. If the `count(AccountSDIF) =1` , then apply a `datediff` function between account created date and Account's task created date.
If the `count(AccountSDIF) > 1` , then apply a `datediff` function between account created date and Account's first task created date.

This is my query to get the count of `AccountID(AccountSDIF)`

```
SELECT 
    A_Std.AccountSFID
    ,COUNT(A_Std.AccountSFID) as Count
FROM [PSA].[Stg_Canonical_Task_Std] AS T_Std 
LEFT JOIN [PSA].[Stg_Canonical_Account_Std] AS A_Std 
  ON T_Std.AccountID = A_Std.AccountSFID 
INNER JOIN [PSA].[Stg_Canonical_Task_Custom] T_Cust 
  on T_Std.[TaskSFID] = T_Cust.[TaskSFID] 
WHERE  T_Cust.Activity_C IN ('Call', 'Email') 
   AND T_Std.Program_Name = 'DowWater'  
   AND T_Std.Status = 'Completed' 
   AND T_Std.AccountID IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY A_Std.AccountSFID
```

[Count of AcccountIds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvMpR.png)

This is my query to get account created date and Account's task created dates.

```
select 
   (A_Std.CreatedDate) as AccountCreatedDate
   ,(T_Std.CreatedDate) as AccountsTaskCreatedDate
   ,A_Std.AccountSFID  
from [PSA].[Stg_Canonical_Task_Std] AS T_Std 
LEFT JOIN [PSA].[Stg_Canonical_Account_Std] AS A_Std 
    ON T_Std.AccountID = A_Std.AccountSFID 
INNER JOIN [PSA].[Stg_Canonical_Task_Custom] T_Cust
    on T_Std.[TaskSFID] = T_Cust.[TaskSFID] 
WHERE  T_Cust.Activity_C IN ('Call', 'Email') 
   AND T_Std.Program_Name = 'DowWater'  
   AND T_Std.Status = 'Completed' 
   AND T_Std.AccountID IS NOT NULL
```

[Account created date and accounts task created date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AnTi.png)

Comment: Those 2 things seem to be the same thing?  Apply datediff between the account created date and the Account's first task created date.  If there is only 1 task then it's created date is automatically the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand:

```
SELECT 
    A_Std.AccountSFID
    ,datediff(A_Std.CREATEDDATE,min(T_Std.TASKCREATEDDATE))
FROM [PSA].[Stg_Canonical_Task_Std] AS T_Std 
LEFT JOIN [PSA].[Stg_Canonical_Account_Std] AS A_Std 
  ON T_Std.AccountID = A_Std.AccountSFID 
INNER JOIN [PSA].[Stg_Canonical_Task_Custom] T_Cust 
  on T_Std.[TaskSFID] = T_Cust.[TaskSFID] 
WHERE  T_Cust.Activity_C IN ('Call', 'Email') 
   AND T_Std.Program_Name = 'DowWater'  
   AND T_Std.Status = 'Completed' 
   AND T_Std.AccountID IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY A_Std.AccountSFID,A_Std.CREATEDDATE
```

Comment: Thank you @avery_larry, it worked perfectly! I always have a lil confusion with the groupby clauses